# Simple NSArray - Bring object to to front NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Simple question for NSarray. I have objects stored in an NSMuteableArray.
[obj1, obj2, obj3]

If an object is chosen, I want to bring this to the front of the array. I.e. if obj3 is chosen, then:

[obj3, obj1, obj2]

Will the below work or duplicate obj3? Also, can this be made thread safe?

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:obj3 atIndex:0];
```

Comment: If you insert obj3 at the front, it will have nothing to do with obj2. After you run that line, your array will be [obj3, obj1, obj2, obj3].

Comment: @DanWatkins sorry, I edited the ? and missed that part. Can I move it to the front WITHOUT adding the object again. And keeping the remaining order intact

Comment: remove it, then add it at the front

Comment: `NSMutableArray * tempArray = [array mutableCopy]; [tempArray removeObject:obj3]; [tempArray insertObject:obj3 atIndex:0]; array = tempArray;`

Comment: @nielsbot thanks! I'm stuck between changing my property from NSMuteable Array to NSArray and manipulating it via the muteableCopy method. This seems easier and thread safe as compared to making the property synchronizsed.

Comment: You will still have to wrap the code in @synchronized (or use a GCD function) if you want to be thread safe. Someone could call your method, your call could be interrupted, and another call to your method could happen. Your array would be mangled.

Comment: @nielsbot by GCD, would dispatch_barrier_async work? I'm currently removing objects on the main queue, adding objects in an async_thread via AFNetworking (downloading objects and adding them one by one). I am switching the order in a completely different thread. Should I use dispatch_barrier_async ? Neither of these operations are time intensive so blocking shouldn't be a huge issue. I can post a full edit if necessary

Comment: wrapping it in @synchronized(self) should be fine.

Comment: but you definitely need synchronization based on your description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you need to preserve the order of the other elements, you need to remove and then insert the object in question:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ... // array with objects
NSInteger index = ... // index of object to move to the front
id obj = array[index];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[array insertObject:obj atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Good answer. (Voted). At first I didn't notice that the OP wanted to shift all the other elements down rather than swapping the item in question with the first item, and was going to suggest `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:` instead, but that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @rmaddy, after revisting this-is there  way to do this with NSPredicate so I don't can perform this on an NSArray and keep it thread safe ?

Answer (score 5):

Your code will insert another reference to `obj3` at the front of the array (ie. the array will now contain 4 elements) but it won't actually duplicate the object.

You need to use `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex` -

```
[myMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex]
```

where `selectedIndex` is the index of the object that was selected.

`NSMutableArray` is not thread safe, so you will need to wrap `@synchronizsed(myMutableArray)` around accesses to this array if you are potentially modifying it from multiple threads or modifying it while another thread is iterating it.

If you want to retain the order of the array beyond the first element then you will need to perform a separate delete and insert operation -

```
id someObject=myMutableArray[selectedIndex];
[myMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
[myMutableArray insertObject:someObject atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't keep the order the same as @rmaddy said

Comment: You could but you would still need to @synchronise the copy operation

Comment: This doesn't give the desired results. Starting with 1,2,3 this gives 3,2,1, not 3.1.2.